# add textbox in DataTable aspx.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

i want to add textBox into dataTable row.I dont know how to do that.Is it possible to add textBox to a dataTable?First it give me this error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

Here is my code:

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" ShowHeader="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <ItemTemplate >
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>                      
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void AddNewRecordRowToGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr;
    dt.TableName = "table";

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Zabeleshka", typeof(TextBox)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    ViewState["marks"] = dt;

    if (ViewState["marks"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["marks"];

        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBox1");

                drCurrentRow["Zabeleshka"] = TextBox1.Text;

                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].Delete();

                    dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["marks"] = dtCurrentTable;

                GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                GridView2.DataBind();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Textbox` is a control and `Datatable` is in-memory table which holds data and not controls, So you need to store the value in datatable and bind the gridview which will have the relevant textbox.

Comment: @RahulSingh now what can I do? - How can i solve this?

Comment: @RahulSingh example?

Answer (score 0):

As your markup code i think you want Text Box inside Gridview with containing some value into that,

for this,
first of all your markup is not correct, the correct one is,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" ShowHeader="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField> <%-- you have not opened it in your markup --%>
        <ItemTemplate >
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>                      
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and in code behind,
to get the textbox value you need

```
TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBox1");
```

edited,

in your code,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[0].FindControl("TextBox1");

                drCurrentRow["Zabeleshka"] = TextBox1.Text;
```

the for loop condition is (i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count)
you should try this (i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count)
because the counting of row is start from 0 and thats why you getting index out of range error.

Comment: i fix that templateField, but all the time it give me this error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: assume that the rows count of your data table is 8 ,but if you want to get access last row the row address would be row[7]. see my answer

Comment: or just simply show me how to pulate label text from textBox

Comment: @buba,actually i m not getting what you want,i think you want gridview containing textbox column binding from datatable,am i right?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a textbox into a gridview no problem then find it from the code behind in the RowDataBound Grid Method. Your problem is more than likely the fact that you have closed your TemplateField and have not opened one. You need to add

```
<asp:TemplateField>
```

above your

```
<ItemTemplate>.
```